EFI variables are not supported and efibootmgr failed to register the boot entry
I'm trying to install grub as my bootloader for my arch linux installation. I am doing this on a virtual machine before I do it on my actual system. I have been following the Arch Installation guide and I have gotten to the point where the it says to install the EFI binaries for the GRUB bootloader. My EFI system partition is mounted and is at mountpoint /mnt/boot from the output of lsblk. The command that the guide is telling me to put in is grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot --bootloader-id=GRUB (after substituting the mount point).
However, when I try to run the command I get:
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
EFI variables are not supported on this system.
EFI variables are not supported on this system.
grub-install: error: efibootmgr failed to register the boot entry: No such file or directory.

I have reinstalled both grub and efibootmgr with pacman -Syu grub and pacman -Syu efibootmgr respectively. I have made sure that I am in chroot and I have followed the guide for the setting up mirrors. I have also made sure that the EFI partition is mounted in the correct mountpoint.
I do not know what the issue is and I would appreciate your help. I don't know if it's important but I'll say again that I am doing this on a virtual machine. Thank you.

1.) Is the EFI partition on your VM FAT32, and marked, efi or esp? 2.)Are your VM settings set to EFI System Type or the Old MSDOS/MBR.  The settings for question 2 can be accessed only while the VM is off.

2.) the VM is not set to EFI, I'm going to fix that first

TL;DR
Changing the Virtual Machine to run EFI fixed the problem. Credit: eyoung100 user.
Story
My Virtual Machine was not set to EFI mode (which I didn't know when I created it). Changing it to EFI resolved the issue.
